# MEF with MVC 5, mixing C# and VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, mef, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a VB.NET Solution that uses MVC 5 and MEF to give me a pluggable web project.

It has a "Host" project that runs and loads all the DLL's dynamically, using MEF, I then load the controllers and everything works nicely. I add a new project, add the Plugin Registration and use MEF to export the controller. Bam, project standalone that fits in my framework.

However, I'd like to now add a C# project instead. I've added the cshtml stuff to my custom ViewEngine, and it copies the views/dll's to the host's plugin directory, however, when rendering the view, I get this error:

Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'CSharpTest' does not exist in the namespace 'MVCMEFPluggable' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

And errors on Line 28:

using MVCMEFPluggable.CSharpTest;

This goes to a temporary file created in the ASP.NET Temporary Files folder. I can remember something about the differences in namespaces when it comes to VB.NET and C#, but I can't figure out what to do to get the view to render properly.

Any insights?

Comment: Just to add on, running through the debugger, the controller is picked up and rendered nicely, it's just when it returns the view when I get that error, so I doubt it's something very serious :)

Comment: can you show us some code? if you want some :)

Comment: It's quite involved, so posting code would be insane really. In the end, it errors on the return view line on the controller. Everything is picked up properly as I mentioned, it's just rendering the view which poses a problem. In the temporary file there's a "using" line as described which is causing the error. No idea why, I suspect it's to do with namespaces but I need to know why so I can actually figure out a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the web.config file the assembly "MVCMEFPluggable.CSharpTest" was added as a reference, removing that line allowed the cshtml to compile and run successfully in the vb.net environment :)